# Multiplication of matrix rows with each other and with another list

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply a matrix containing voxel sizes with a list of single numbers (containing the amount of voxels). Something like this:

```
a = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
b = [5, 6]

hocuspocus = [1 * 2 * 3 * 5, 2 * 3 * 4 * 6] = [30, 144]
```

Because I need to provide the voxels in cubic millimeters, I need to multiply the content of each matrix row with each other and then with list b. Haven't yet figured out how to do that in python. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for something like this, which uses the `prod()` function to multiply all numbers in a row and reduce them in a single value, and then the `for` statement of this list comprehension iterates the two lists `a` and `b` and multiplies them element-wise.

### Python 3.7 or older

```
from functools import reduce  # Required in Python 3.
from operator import mul

def prod(iterable): # This function multiplies all numbers of a row.
    return reduce(mul, iterable, 1)
    
a = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
b = [5, 6]
    
out = [prod(row) * elem for row, elem in zip(a, b)]

print(out)
```

### Python 3.8+

Alternatively you could use the native `prod()` function in the `math` module.

```
from math import prod
    
a = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
b = [5, 6]
    
out = [prod(row) * elem for row, elem in zip(a, b)]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[30, 144]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the fast answer! I have beed trying to solve this problem for so long and it perfectly worked out with your help! Thank you!